# Organize dictionary by frequency

Tags: python, dictionary

I create a dictionary for the most used words and get the top ten. I need to sort this for the list, which should be in order. I can't do that without making a list, which I can't use. Here is my code. I am away dictionaries cannot be sorted, but i still  need help.

```
most_used_words = Counter()
zewDict = Counter(most_used_words).most_common(10)
newDict = dict(zewDict)
keys = newDict.keys()
values = newDict.values()
msg = ('Here is your breakdown of your most used words: \n\n'
       'Word | Times Used'
       '\n:--:|:--:'
       '\n' + str(keys[0]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[0]) +
       '\n' + str(keys[1]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[1]) +
       '\n' + str(keys[2]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[2]) +
       '\n' + str(keys[3]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[3]) +
       '\n' + str(keys[4]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[4]) +
       '\n' + str(keys[5]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[5]) +
       '\n' + str(keys[6]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[6]) +
       '\n' + str(keys[7]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[7]) +
       '\n' + str(keys[8]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[8]) +
       '\n' + str(keys[9]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[9]))
r.send_message(user, 'Most Used Words', msg)
```

How would I do it so the msg prints the words in order from most used word on the top to least on the bottom with the correct values for the word?

Edit: I know dictionaries cannot be sorted on their own, so can I work around this somehow?

Comment: Tip: Use an `OrderedDict` it keeps the keys in the order of insertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common): `most_common([n])`

> Return a list of the n most common elements and their counts from the
>   most common to the least. If n is not specified, most_common() returns
>   all elements in the counter. Elements with equal counts are ordered
>   arbitrarily:

```
>>> Counter('abracadabra').most_common(3)
[('a', 5), ('r', 2), ('b', 2)]
```

---

Your code can be:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(most_used_words)
msg = "Here is your breakdown of your most used words:\n\nWords | Times Used\n:--:|:--:\n"
msg += '\n'.join('%s|%s' % (k.capitalize(), v) for (k, v) in c.most_common(10))
r.send_message(user, 'Most Used Words', msg)
```

Comment: This was the one. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

Once you have the `values` it's as simple as:

```
print('Word | Times Used')
for e, t in collections.Counter(values).most_common(10):
    print("%s|%d" % (e,t))
```

Print something like:

```
Word | Times Used
e|4
d|3
a|2
c|2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import operator
newDict = dict(zewDict)

sorted_newDict = sorted(newDict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
msg = ''
for key, value in sorted_newDict:
  msg.append('\n' + str(key).capitalize() + '|' + str(value))
```

This will sort by the dictionary values. If you want it in the other order add `reverse=True` to `sorted()`.

Comment: Better to use `.most_common` here

Comment: It is better to format strings, concating strings is much slower.